# How to crop a part of image in the different matrix, but the matrix doesn't change its size in openCV.

Tags: c++, image, opencv, matrix, crop

I'm doing a project using openCV 2.4 ver. C++
I want to crop a part of image and save it in a different Matrix. Instead of getting a new single cropped image every loop, the cropped_image keeps previous images, and keeps building on next to the previous image. I wasn't sure what I did wrong..

Also this loops stops when n = 64 and m = 240. I also don't understand why..

Can anyone help me?

openCV 2.4v C++

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

original_image = imread("image.jpg",1);
int n, m, cols_ss, rows_ss; 
int cols = 640;
int rows = 480;
cols_ss = 64 // arbitrary number;
rows_ss = 48 // arbitrary number;
Mat cropped_image;

for (n = 0; n < cols - cols_ss; n = n + cols_ss) {
    for (m = 0; m < rows - rows_ss; m = m + rows_ss) {

        // initialize cropped_image as zeros. 
        Mat cropped_image(cols_ss, rows_ss, CV_8UC1, Scalar::all(0));

        // Crop a small part of an original_image to cropped_image. 
        cropped_image = original_image(Rect(n, m, n + cols_ss, m + rows_ss));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on OpenCV docs, the constructor for `Rect` are `Rect(x, y, width, height)`. Are you sure you don't mean `cropped_image = original_image(Rect(n, m, cols_ss, rows_ss));`?

ROI function gives 1:1 mapping to an area in image via pointer. Another way to make sure `cropped_image` is as intended, use:

```
Mat cropped_image(original_image, Rect(n, m, cols_ss, rows_ss));
```

This would make sure `cropped_image`'s size is determined by ROI's `Rect`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I didn't get the any errors after I changed from "n + cols_ss" to "cols_ss".
However, it seemed the cropped image did not move around. When I displaied the image with imshow("temp_window",cropped_image). it showed me same image again, instead of scanning the image...

Comment: Just to make sure, did you change the `n + cols_ss` in `for` loop? You should not.

Comment: No. I kept the same in the for loop. 
I added following code to see changes in pixels:

   f1_patch = sum(cropped_image)[0];
   cout << "f1 is: " << f1_patch << endl;

Comment: I didn't know I have to made a comment within a 5min.. 

No. I kept the same in the for loop. 
I added following code to see changes in pixels:

   f1_patch = sum(cropped_image)[0];
   cout << "f1 is: " << f1_patch << endl;
                        
                        namedWindow("temp",1);
                        imshow("temp",cropped_iamge);

Display screens kept showing me same spot, however the sum of pixels were a lot different. The image came from a webcam in real time, and I set the delay to be 0.5s.